# Getting window class info from another process

Tags: winapi

*GetClassInfoEx* fails when called for a class that was defined in another process, for both string name and class atom. I have observed that `ConsoleWindowClass`, which is returned for console windows, doesn't work when passed to *GetClassInfo(Ex)*, as it is defined in conhost.exe.

Is it possible to obtain the class info from this process, possibly with *ReadProcessMemory*, without having to inject custom code into the process?

Comment: Inject into the other process.

Comment: Why do you need this information? The implementation of ConsoleWindowClass is internal and changes from version to version, so anything you do with it may stop working at any time.

Comment: @RaymondChen Don't worry, just curiosity. I was simply experimenting with *GetClassInfoEx* and was a bit surprised when it didn't work for classes from other processes, given that working with windows from other processes is just fine.

Comment: GetClassInfo returns pointers and GDI objects, both of which are meaningful only within the process that created them.

Comment: @RaymondChen Well, reading another process' memory is no difficulty, at least for LPCTSTR.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. But returning a pointer that is not immediately usable is typically restricted to debugging APIs.